# Create an alert that depends on a limit order

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to create an alert that is triggered only if the limit order is reached, can you help me?

```
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("Long Exit", "long", limit=long_tp_price, stop=long_sl_price, comment="Exit_Long")
    alert('CloseMarket_SL_or_TPlong')

if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit("Short Exit", "short", limit=short_tp_price, stop=short_sl_price, comment="Exit_Short")
    alert('CloseMarket_SL_or_TPshort')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from `v5`, [strategy.exit()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit) has multiple alert arguments which you can use.

> **alert_profit (series string)** Text that will replace the '{{strategy.order.alert_message}}' placeholder when one is used in the
> "Message" field of the "Create Alert" dialog. Only replaces the text
> if the exit was triggered by crossing `profit` or `limit`
> specifically. Optional. The default is na.
>
> **alert_loss (series string)** Text that will replace the '{{strategy.order.alert_message}}' placeholder when one is used in the
> "Message" field of the "Create Alert" dialog. Only replaces the text
> if the exit was triggered by crossing `stop` or `loss` specifically.
> Optional. The default is na.
>
> **alert_trailing (series string)** Text that will replace the '{{strategy.order.alert_message}}' placeholder when one is used in the
> "Message" field of the "Create Alert" dialog. Only replaces the text
> if the exit was triggered by crossing `trail_offset` specifically.
> Optional. The default is na.